# Heroku Building an Add-on (undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

## heroku_controller.rb

```
class HerokuController < ApplicationController

    def resources
    service = Service.create!(
      plan: json_params[:plan],
      region: json_params[:region],
      heroku_uuid: json_params[:uuid] # Will be present in all future requests
    )

    response = {
      id: service.id, # Unique identifier from your system
      config: { "SERVICE_URL" => service.url },
      message: "Welcome to our service"
    }

    status 200
    response.to_json

    end
  end


 response = {
   id: service.id, # Unique identifier from your system
   config: { "SERVICE_URL" => service.url },
   message: "Welcome to our service"
 }

 status 200
 response.to_json

 end
end
```

I dont understand how to create this is Service.create! 
I shoud create the new model, or what?

## addon-manifest.json

```
     {
      "id": "aaaaaaa",
      "api": {
        "config_vars": [ "AAAAAAA_URL" ],
        "requires": [],
        "regions": [ "us" ],
        "password": "531fe5d8558846c99383ad4cad196d66",
        "sso_salt": "b8f0e46bb9d7b0ca4cf35a21bcb8ff97",
        "production": {
          "base_url": "https://yourapp.com/heroku/resources",
          "sso_url": "https://yourapp.com/sso/login"
        },
        "test": {
          "base_url": "http://localhost:3000/heroku/resources",
          "sso_url": "http://localhost:3000/sso/login",
          "message": "sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"
        },
        "version": "3"
      }
    }
```

## terminal.log

Parameters: {"heroku_id"=>"app2431@kensa.heroku.com", "plan"=>"test", "callback_url"=>"http://localhost:7779/callback/999", "logplex_token"=>nil, "region"=>"amazon-web-services::us-east-1", "options"=>{}, "uuid"=>"2570ced0-25a4-45f8-9fc4-ca38855a6527", "heroku"=>{"heroku_id"=>"app2431@kensa.heroku.com", "plan"=>"test", "callback_url"=>"http://localhost:7779/callback/999", "logplex_token"=>nil, "region"=>"amazon-web-services::us-east-1", "options"=>{}, "uuid"=>"2570ced0-25a4-45f8-9fc4-ca38855a6527"}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 154ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NameError (undefined local variable or method `service' for #):

app/controllers/heroku_controller.rb:7:in `resources'

Comment: Don't you have the Service model?

Comment: no :(  But my teacher said what this is example can work without model, but i dont understand... he said :why using model, if u can use adapter rest api... And i confused...

Comment: If you use create, Rails will try to insert the record in a table called services. But I'm not really sure, what's the heroku_controller.rb line number 7?

Comment: line #7  service = Service.create!